# Justifying housework / keeping one’s home clean and tidy

Tags: sources-mekorot, home-house, cleaning

Shalom.

I was wondering if someone could provide me with sources in support of regular housework / keeping one’s home clean and tidy / beautifying one’s home.

A source / warrant from G-d would make encouraging one’s children or the lazy to tidy up messy / dirty places much easier.

Many thanks.

Comment: Half support: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Berakhot.57b.12?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simcha_Zissel_Ziv

Comment: Two essential Talmudic sources that I can think of off hand are *B'rachos* 57b ("שלשה מרחיבין דעתו של אדם אלו הן דירה נאה ואשה נאה וכלים נאים"), indicating the mental and emotional benefits of keeping a nice home, and *P'sachim* 111b ("פארי בביתא קשי לעניותא נשורא בביתא קשי לעניותא בלילי שבתות ובלילי רביעית שרו מזיקין עילויה איסרא דמזוני נקיד שמיה איסרא דעניותא נבל שמיה"), indicating that a filthy home leads to poverty and perhaps implying that a person should clean their home at least twice per week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about the rest of the week, but as a starting point, we are enjoined to make an effort before the onset of Shabbat.

It writes in [Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chayim 262:1)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.262.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> לקדש השבת בשלחן ערוך ובכסות נקיה: ובו ג"ס
> י**סדר שלחנו ויציע המטות ויתקן כל ענייני הבית כדי שימצאנו ערוך ומסודר בבואו מבה"כ**: הגה ויהיה שלחנו ערוך כל יום השבת וכן המנהג ואין לשנות (טור ס"ס רפ"ט ומרדכי פ' כל כתבי והגהות מיי' פ' כ"ט דשבת):
>
> To Sanctify Shabbat With a Set Table and Clean Clothes: 3 Seifim: (1) **One should set his table and take his cushions and arrange the appearances of the house, so that we should find it arranged and ordered when he returns from Synagogue**. RAMA: It is that our tables are kept set all of Shabbat and such is the custom and one shouldn't change it. (Tur; Mordechai; Hagahos Maimoni)

And the [Aruch Hashulchan 262:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.262.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) adds "ויטאטא הבית" - that the house should be swept.

Answer (score 3):

I found an interesting source about this which warns not to be too uptight about getting one's children to clean the house:

> יש לתמוה מה שכתוב בתורה והנה טוב מאד כמה פעמים במעשה בראשית. ובמשנה תורה כתיב ראה נתתי לפניך את החיים ואת הטוב את המות ואת הרע. מהיכן בא הרע. אבל אין לפרש כמו שאנו אומרים רע ממש אלא הרע הוא ג"כ טוב. רק שהוא מדריגה תחתונה מהטוב גמור. וזהו רמוז בזוהר מלעיל ומלרע וזהו כשפועלים טוב אז הרע ג"כ נעשה טוב. אבל כשחוטאים ח"ו אז נעשה רע ממש למשל המכבד את הבית שעשוי לפנות את הבית והוא טוב קצת אבל הוא במדריגה תחתונה. ועכ"פ טוב הוא. וכשצריך להכות בו את התינוק שהוא חוטא אזי הוא המכבד נעשה רע גמור ומכין בו את התינוק:
>
> [צוואת הריב"ש](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tzavaat_HaRivash.1.85?vhe=Warsaw_1913&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

(Translation of the relevant part) Tidying  the house, in order to clear out the house, is a somewhat good thing. However, it is a low level, but at least it is good. And when one must hit the child (to get him to clean), which is a sin, then the tidying becomes a totally bad thing, and one comes to hitting the child. (I think that means, even if one thinks he will just ask the child to clean and not hit him, he will end up hitting.)